# Eclipse comment/uncomment shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I thought this would be easy to achieve, but so far I haven't found solutions for comment/uncomment shortcut on both `Java class editor` and `jsf faceted webapp XHTML file editor` :

1. to quickly comment/uncomment a line (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> is for removing single line)
2. being able to choose multiple lines and comment/uncomment it

---

**For example :**

**single line java code**, from :

```
private String name;
```

into

```
//private String name;
```

---

**multiple line java code**, from :

```
private String name;
private int age;
```

into

```
/*private String name;
private int age;*/
```

---

**single line xhtml code**, from :

```
<h:inputText ... />
```

into

```
<!-- h:inputText ... / -->
```

---

**multiple line xhtml code**, from :

```
<h:inputTextarea
  rows="xx"
  cols="yy"
  ...
/>
```

into

```
<!-- h:inputTextarea
  rows="xx"
  cols="yy"
  ...
/ -->
```

---

Comment: for single line comment you can use `ctrl + /`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to comment a block in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001586/how-to-comment-a-block-in-eclipse)

Comment: Mac shortcuts: // for single line comments toggle Cmd + / to insert and remove. /* multiline */ use Cntrl + Cmd + // to comment and Cntrl + Cmd + \\ to uncomment. Works with Eclipse Neon too!

Comment: Any shortcuts to uncomment this type of comment                                  /**Hello                                                                                                           *this is second line                                                                                      *this is third line */

Answer (score 373, accepted):

For single line comment you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and for multiple line comment you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> after selecting the lines you want to comment in java editor.

On Mac/OS X you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment out single lines or selected blocks.

Comment: cool ! works great for both java and xhtml file. it even uses the **/* */** for multiline java codes

Comment: Using a swedish Keyboard the multiline is not possible since the '/' char is typed using shift + 7, is there a plugin to change the shortcuts for Swedish users?

Comment: @DavidMårtensson it works fine for me, just press Ctrl + Shift + 7 (yielding ctrl + /), having multiple lines marked.

Comment: how does one undo a commented field in eclipse?

Comment: To uncomment press Ctrl + / again if it is a single line comment and Ctrl + Shift + \ if it is a multi line comment

Comment: @Richie ctrl + shift + \ doesnt work for me for uncommenting multiple lines

Comment: OP asked for comment uncomment both Please update the answer

Comment: This doesn't uncomment in my case.

Comment: Doesn't answer question!  Doesn't show how to UNcomment!

Answer (score 195):

Use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> which will open a list of all major shortcuts for eclipse.

1. For **single line java code** comment and uncomment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (Forward
   Slash)
2. For **multiple line java code** comment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>/</kbd> (Forward Slash) and

   Multiline uncomment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>\</kbd> (Backslash)
3. For **single line xhtml code** comment/uncomment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>c</kbd>
4. For **multiple line xhtml code** comment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>/</kbd> (Forward Slash)

   For multiple uncomment : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
   <kbd>\</kbd> (Backward Slash)

**For Mac user it will be:** <kbd>⌘</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Found it ! It's ctrl shift c in my eclipse, and toggle comment/uncomment works for both java code and xhtml file. But the comment on java code use **//** even for multiple line, and not **/* */** .. but i think it's ok :-)

Comment: @bertie Use #4 if that's the effect you're going for.

Comment: replace ctrl with ⌘, thanks for teaching me for teaching me how to fish!

Comment: For multiple uncomment : Ctrl + Shift + \ (Backward Slash) : Most IMPORTANT!

Answer (score 103):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>

does comment/uncomment in the Java Editor.

Comment: This works for Android application. I swapped that to Ctrl+Q.

Comment: This is a great because it's simpler than remembering two different commands for comment/un-comment!

Comment: in contrast to most other answers this will always work (multiline comments cannot be nested)

Answer (score 52):

1. Single line **comment** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
2. Single line **uncomment** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

---

3. Multiline **comment** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
4. Multiline **uncomment** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note the backslash)

Comment: Single line stopped working in Eclipse 2021

Answer (score 36):

An easier way is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, just like in Code::Blocks

Comment: Thank you. In my keyboard I have to press **Alt Gr** to access **/** and the common shortcuts don't work (ctrl + / and ctrl + shift + /). This shortcut is what I needed.

Comment: This is awesome because it uncomments XML. When I use Cmd-/ to uncomment XML/HTML, I end up with a nested comment.

Answer (score 20):

Select the code you want to comment, then use <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> also to uncomment. It may not work for all types of source files, but it works great for Java code.

Answer (score 14):

In eclipse Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, will list all the shortcuts.

Comment: this answer actually more meaning full. gives answer for wide range of other shortcut related questions, in addition to what question is asked here

Comment: ..but it does not answer the question because "comment" hot key is not listed in this popup.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> . Works great on **.java**, **.xhtml**, **.properties** and maybe on others but I only tested these ones. Can comment single or multiple lines.

Comment: yes, also works at least in `.less, .css, .jsp, .xml`

Answer (score 10):

---

### Comments In Java class

---

1. ***Toggle/Single line Comment*** ( **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>** ) - Add/remove line comments (//…) from the current line.
2. ***Add Block Comment*** ( **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>** ) - Wrap the selected lines in a block comment (/*… */).
3. ***Remove Block Comment*** ( **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>** ) - Remove a block comment (/*… */) surrounding the selected lines.
4. ***Add Javadoc Comment*** ( **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>** ) - Add a Javadoc comment to the active field/method/class.

---

## Comments In HTML/XML/Config file

---

1. ***Add Block Comment*** ( **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>** ) - Wrap the selected lines in a block comment (< !-- -->).
2. ***Remove Block Comment*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>) - Remove a block comment (< !-- -->) surrounding the selected lines.

Comment: HAHA, by desesperally trying to uncomment in XML with `CTRL+SHIFT+\ ` , I discovered a new one `CTRL+ALT-GR+8` that seems to duplicate (vertical split) current edited file in 2 editors. Then you can see head and bottom of same file at same time

Answer (score 9):

For those who like to customize things (and screw them up), some tips:

In "Preferences" - "General" - "Keys", type "comment" to get a full list of comment key combination in all editors. Be sure only to edit, not copy commands(because you cannot erase created ones).

For HTML files, look for those with scope "Editing HTML files". The names are confusing, yes, but the description shows more or less when each and every key is used.

At last, I am only able to define block comment in HTML here. It works for both HTML code and Javascript code(add at the beginning and the end, `<!--` and `-->` if is HTML, and add `/*` and `*/` if is Javascript). (I remember once there may be a "line comment" key (add comments for every line) but now it is not there anymore. If someone knows how to find it and tell me, I will be very grateful.)
[image]
**The category must be `Edit`.** `Source` does not work.

EDIT:

I found how to configure XML Toggle comment! **The category should be `Edit`, too. Then you can toggle comment in **XML Editor**(the one with "Design" and "Source" tabs).

[image]

Comment: On Maverics / Eclipse oxygen I got it to work by setting binding = command + shift + / , when = 'editing javascript source' where category = source and command = 'add block comment' .

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>7</kbd>  to comment a selected text.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way of doing is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, on the lines of your code.

For comment and for uncomment do same .. :)

Comment: Thanks this lead me to try cmd ⌘ + shift + c (essentially the same thing) to toggle comments on a on a mac

Comment: Its only working for only comment and uncomment instructions.

Answer (score 6):

For a Mac it is the following combination: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: just for future reference: That key is called the "command-key".

Comment: @katzenhut I would hope a programmer would know what the keys on his/her keyboard are.

Comment: @b1nary.atr0phy - well, when i wrote this comment the answerer referred to the key in question as the "mac-key". so what does that tell you? luckily, somebody edited it since...

Comment: My boss forced me to use a Mac-Book back then. Not my fault i didn't know the buttons name :-)

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to toggle "//" comments and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift/</kbd> to toggle "/* */" comments. At least for Java, anyway - other tooling may have different shortcuts.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> will remove a block of either comment, but won't add comments.

EDIT: It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on a PC, but on a Mac the shortcuts may all be <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead. I don't have a Mac myself, so can't easily check

Answer (score 4):

Single comment <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and also multiple line comment you can select multiple line and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>. Then, to remove comment you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> for both single line and multiple line comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle the comment on one line or selection by using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
This adds/removes the // infront of the code line

You can block comment /*  */ using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + / eclipse shortcut

You can find a complete list of useful eclipse shortcuts here http://javatutorial.net/eclipse-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

Source -> Remove Block Comment

[link](https://www.benchresources.net/how-to-comment-and-uncomment-line-block-in-eclipse-ide/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Ctrl + / stopped working for me in Eclipse 2021, due to conflicts of the same command.  If you go into Eclipse Preferences Generic Keys and then filter by "comment" you can then click on each Toggle Comment to see if there are any conflicts.  Remove conflicts by clicking on the command and clicking Unbind Command, and this fixed it for me: [image]