# Shortcut for comment Ctrl+7 in eclipse doesn t work

Tags: php, eclipse

I use Eclipse for PHP Developers ( Helios SR2) in Mac OS X.
I'm used to use Cmd + 7 in Windows, for Java. Here it doesn't work ( The equivalent Apple + 7)
I went to preferences > General > Key, and try to change shortcut.
 I have 5 lines about Add Comment block, I change all 5, but I can't get it working with my personal shortcut. Also, I have U in user column.

What should I do???

Tx!

Comment: this is what I do! I expressed badly ( Apple = cmd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for single comment to use as **CMD + /** or **CMD + 7** after editing/selecting line.

Notice: From Windows CTRL on APPLE is CMD key! So use as

CMD + 7

CMD + /

Comment: It is not working ! if I do it in ADT ( Eclipse for Android), it just work fine, but in Eclipse for PHP, I can't make it work

Comment: Try there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut

Comment: It's not working, that's why I post. When I press Cmd + Shift + 7, Eclipse Help menu get active...

Comment: Try post there and describe your version, what you are doing and check for bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/