# Toggle comments in FDT?

Tags: fdt

Is there a way to do the shortcut commenting described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut), in [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) when doing Action Script 3 coding?

That is, something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment or uncomment one or more lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer after looking at [this](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Shortcuts) FDT shortcuts page. The page doesn't really list many of the shortcuts available, but rather suggests trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> from within FDT to see a list of all possible shortcuts.

Near the bottom of the list under `Toggle Comment`, the answer is found to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.