# How do you set a keyboard shortcut to (block) comment out highlighted lines with the hash sign (#) in a Gherkin feature file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, gherkin

Is there a way to set a keyboard shortcut in Eclipse to add the hash/pound sign (#) to the beginning of all highlighted lines in a Gherkin *.feature file? (I have the Cucumber for Eclipse plugin installed, which provides syntax highlighting for these files - not sure if that helps or is relevant.)

Ideally, the same command that toggles comments in Java files, `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/`, would be assigned.

Could this be achieved with Text Completion features, if shortcut settings on their own can't do it?

Has anyone got a link to a manual of how to add keyboard shortcuts to Eclipse? is there a plugin for that? The GUI doesn't seem to support it...

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5534748/1668057) may get you closer...

Comment: Also, as Cucumber/Gherkin treats a `#` which appears as the first non-whitespace character as a commented line, you may find binding a new shortcut in Eclipse to a script which prepends the current line(s) with a `#` will work as desired.