# Uncomment multiple lines in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to uncomment multiple line of code in eclipse, but whenever i tried to use ctl+Shift+/ it recomment the whole line of code. can anybody tell the shortcut

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse comment/uncomment shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `C` to toggle comments marks.
Or `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `\` to uncomment.

More info on the `Source` tab in the main menu. Or in the Key assistant: `CTRL`+ `SHIFT`+ `L`

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTRL + SHIFT + C to add comments marks. And CTRL + SHIFT + \ to uncomment.