# How do you uncomment on a saved code that you turned into a comment

Tags: java, eclipse

Today is my first time learning Java and I have learn lots of shortcuts. One of them is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> which makes a line of code into a single line comment. After saving a specific Java script, I realised that 35+ lines of codes are now comments and I cannot turn it back into a code after the save. How can I remove it again?

```
//      int age = 12;

//      double amount = 100.00;

//      System.out.println(age);

//      System.out.println("Amount: " + amount);
```

(this is the saved version)

If you would like to recreate this problem, copy and save this in Eclipse, come back to that file and try to uncomment, and if you do manage to find a way, please share it.

It's a Java class, with public static void main option checked, within a Java project.

Comment: Use Cntrl+Shift+\  ;-)

Comment: Please add the code in specific code blocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse comment/uncomment shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut)

Answer (score 2):

You can select the block and use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>.

Alternatively, right-click on the selection and then use the **Source » Remove Block Comment** option.